# Default GCP project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I have multiple projects how do I specify which one gets used by default?

With gcloud I see that I have a project active in the "default configuration" but when I run my local software that is interacting with the Compute Engine API a different project gets used (as shown via the web console).

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a Project from your local clients depend upon the authentication process. You can find some examples [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) in the documentation, according to what client are you using, for setting the Project.

Comment: Hi. LIke I said, I am authenticated via `gcloud`. Now I want to use my own tool. This tool only worked when I associated a service account with a GCP Project, turned on billing, linked billing to the Project, enabled the Compute Engine API, and assigned a few roles to the service account. It works. But then I got to think about how I could create a second Project and apply the tool to it. How do I associate my tool to a project?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you mention "tool", do you mean a software done by you that is using the Client Libraries?

Answer (score 0):

So I neglected to appreciate that the service agent is actually contained within the project. That's the piece I was missing. It all makes sense now and testing confirmed my understanding.